# How to create a phonebook in c# through dictionary via inputstream?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am new to programming...please someone help writing this program.

this is the code i have written so far....i know there are so many mistakes please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution
{ 
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> phonebook = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (string name in phonenumber)
        {
            phonebook.Add("name", num);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `int` is a really bad choice for storing phone numbers - since they can start with `0`. as for help in writing the program: what ***specific problem*** do you have? just asking for help in general is too broad and off-topic for SO. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i thought people will help me write the program here...sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("How many entries?");
            int entries;
            if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out entries))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must enter a valid number");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            Dictionary<string, string> phonebook = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for(int i = 0; i < entries; i++)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Enter name:");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter phone number:");
                string number = Console.ReadLine();
                phonebook.Add(name, number);
            }
            // do something with your dictionary object
        }
    }
}
```